# Email setting in wordpress

Tags: email

I have a WordPress website that works perfect without any problem, In the front end i have a contact page with a contact form, when i set the receiving email to any email using ( Googole, Yahoo, or Hotmail) the email arrives to the destination without any problem , but when emails send to (example@company.com) no email received.

What to change or configure in my website since this is the first time to face a problem like this.

Comment: This is not always related to wordpress. Sending emails to and from a wordpress site is controlled by your host's spam filters. Some hosts I've used in the past, usually low end, I have experienced this problem. Their spam filters is set so sensitive that even normal emails are recognized as spam, thus blocking the email. I think you should start at your host.

Comment: I will try your advice @PieterGoosen and i hope it will be the problem from the hosting company, for now i will send email with my problem to them so they can check their spam filters. Thanks